# Generics: casting and value types, why is this illegal?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0, casting

Why is this a compile time error?

```
public TCastTo CastMe<TSource, TCastTo>(TSource i)
{
     return (TCastTo)i;
}
```

Error:

> Cannot convert type 'TSource' to 'TCastTo'

And why is this a runtime error?

```
public TCastTo CastMe<TSource, TCastTo>(TSource i)
{
     return (TCastTo)(object)i;
}

int a = 4;
long b = CastMe<int, long>(a); // InvalidCastException

// this contrived example works
int aa = 4;
int bb = CastMe<int, int>(aa);

// this also works, the problem is limited to value types
string s = "foo";
object o = CastMe<string, object>(s);
```

I've searched SO and the internet for an answer to this and found lots of explanations on similar generic related casting issues, but I can't find anything on this particular simple case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Why is this a compile time error?

The problem is that every possible combination of value types has *different* rules for what a cast means.  Casting a 64 bit double to a 16 bit int is completely different code from casting a decimal to a float, and so on. The number of possibilities is enormous. So think like the compiler. **What code is the compiler supposed to generate for your program?**

The compiler would have to generate code that *starts the compiler again at runtime, does a fresh analysis of the types, and dynamically emits the appropriate code*.

That seems like perhaps more work and less performance than you expected to get with generics, so we simply outlaw it. If what you really want is for the compiler to start up again and do an analysis of the types, use "dynamic" in C# 4; that's what it does.

> And why is this a runtime error?

Same reason.

A boxed int may only be unboxed to int (or int?), for the same reason as above; if the CLR tried to do every possible conversion from a boxed value type to every other possible value type then essentially it has to *run a compiler again at runtime*.  That would be unexpectedly slow.

> So why is it not an error for reference types?

Because **every reference type conversion is the same as every other reference type conversion**: you interrogate the object to see if it is derived from or identical to the desired type. If it's not, you throw an exception (if doing a cast) or result in null/false (if using the "as/is" operators).  The rules are consistent for reference types in a way that they are not for value types.  Remember *reference types know their own type*.  Value types do not; with value types, *the variable doing the storage is the only thing that knows the type semantics that apply to those bits*. Value types *contain their values and no additional information*.  Reference types contain their values plus lots of extra data.

For more information see my article on the subject:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/

Comment: How does the performance of `dynamic` compare to creating and compiling an expression tree (and caching the resulting delegate)?

Comment: @Ben: That's precisely what dynamic does; the DLR performs the type analysis, constructs an expression tree, compiles it and caches the result. The next time the code is encountered, the DLR consults its cache, determines if the types match close enough to re-use the cached state, and reuses it if possible.

Comment: @Eric: Ok, then which is more efficient, the DLR cache lookup, or fetching a static member of a generic class?  It seems that when the type is known as a generic parameter, doing the expression tree stuff explicitly may be slightly faster than entrusting it to `dynamic`.

Comment: @Ben: Sure, perhaps. Does it matter? Asking which kind of expression tree compilation is "more efficient" is rather like asking which 1970's Cadillac is more fuel efficient. If you care about fuel efficiency, don't be driving a 1970's Caddy in the first place. Any solution involving an expression tree is going to be orders of magnitude more expensive than doing a statically-determined cast. Expression trees are heavyweight.

Comment: @Eric: Compiling the expression tree is expensive.  Calling the cached delegate is rather cheap (maybe one order of magnitude worse than a static cast).  It's the cache lookup I'm asking about.

Comment: @Ben: Ah, I see your point. I don't know. You'll have to measure it!

Comment: @Eric, don't you mean using the "as" operator? (if using the "as" operator)

Comment: Thanks Eric (and everyone else, all great answers). I guess I knew less about casting in C# than I thought I did.

Comment: @Mark: Sure. is, as, whatever. Same thing under the covers. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx

Comment: @Ben it is possible to make use of the convertability from a Func<double,int> to Func<X,Y> so long as, at runtime X is a double and Y is int. Using this you can cerate the conversion method for any types required and stash them away in a static class generesized on X and Y whose static constructor (which will run once for any X,Y pair) validates that the conversion is legal, creates a delataget to do it, casts the delate to the gemeric types, sotres it in a static variable on itself for use later. You then pay a one off cost per conversion type pair...

Comment: ...the useage ends up being a generic static lookup (this is slower than a normal static lookup, we're talking a ~hundred cycles here plus a delegate call. Overall it's pretty fast for my needs.

Comment: what is required however is implementing the conversion rules (these are laif out nicely in section 13 of the spec, but will take you some time do do correctly (if you don't need some of them feel free to leave throwing NotImplementedException)

Comment: Nitpick - a boxed int can also be unboxed as an int?, unfortunately.

Comment: @Shuggy: That's pretty much exactly what I am talking about, but I don't think any casting of delegates is actually necessary.

Comment: @Ben I hadn't access to 4.0 as I wrote it. Also I had to option to allow unbox+implicit conversion on numeric types. the dynamic one is the way to go for simplicity though.

Comment: @Shuggy: You don't need `dynamic`, just `Expression`, which IIRC was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Ben Oh you mean construct the expression directly, yes that would have been an elegant solution. I've found the results of that become a pain to debug through though so I'm happy with the current approach. Using it for some of the more trial ones might have saved me some time though.

Comment: @Shuggy: Should be as simple as `ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource)); return Expression.Lambda<Converter<TSource, TCastTo>(Expression.Convert(p, typeof(TCastTo), p).Compile();`

Answer (score 7):

C# uses one cast syntax for multiple different underlying operations:

- upcast
- downcast
- boxing
- unboxing
- numeric conversion
- user-defined conversion

In generic context, the compiler has no way of knowing which of those is correct, and they all generate different MSIL, so it bails out.

By writing `return (TCastTo)(object)i;` instead, you force the compiler to do an upcast to `object`, followed by a downcast to `TCastTo`.  The compiler will generate code, but if that wasn't the right way to convert the types in question, you'll get a runtime error.

---

Code Sample:

```
public static class DefaultConverter<TInput, TOutput>
{
    private static Converter<TInput, TOutput> cached;

    static DefaultConverter()
    {
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
        cached = Expression.Lambda<Converter<TSource, TCastTo>(Expression.Convert(p, typeof(TCastTo), p).Compile();
    }

    public static Converter<TInput, TOutput> Instance { return cached; }
}

public static class DefaultConverter<TOutput>
{
     public static TOutput ConvertBen<TInput>(TInput from) { return DefaultConverter<TInput, TOutput>.Instance.Invoke(from); }
     public static TOutput ConvertEric(dynamic from) { return from; }
}
```

Eric's way sure is shorter, but I think mine should be faster.

Comment: I sort of regret asking this now because further exploring suggests generics aren't really involved here. As in C# even `string s = "s"; Type t = (Type)s;` is a compile time error. And this is a runtime error: `int a = 4; long b = (long)(object)a;`, so I can get both errors without using generics. Possibly generics do throw some kind of unseen wrench in there?

Comment: @Matt: (Unconstrained) generics prevent the compiler from making any attempt to figure out what conversion you need.  But doing the wrong style conversion causes failure whether generics were involved or not.

Answer (score 3):

The compile error is caused because TSource cannot be implicitly cast to TCastTo. The two types may share a branch on their inheritance tree, but there is no guarantee. If you wanted to call only types that did share an ancestor, you should modify the CastMe() signature to use the ancestor type instead of generics.

The runtime error example avoids the error in your first example by first casting the TSource i to an object, something all objects in C# derive from. While the compiler doesn't complain (because object -> something that derives from it, could be valid), the behaviour of casting via (Type)variable syntax will throw if the cast is invalid. (The same problem that the compiler prevented from happening in example 1).

Another solution, which does something similar to what you're looking for...

```
    public static T2 CastTo<T, T2>(T input, Func<T, T2> convert)
    {
        return convert(input);
    }
```

You'd call it like this.

```
int a = 314;
long b = CastTo(a, i=>(long)i);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I don't entirely understand why `long b = (long)someInt;` works, but `long b = (long)((object)someInt);` doesn't.  What about casting the int to object first breaks the cast to long? Do you know?

Comment: Because the first one means numeric conversion, and the second one means unboxing (conversion from `object` to a value type is always unboxing, conversion from `object` to a reference type is always a downcast).  Since a numeric conversion is needed, the code that causes unboxing just doesn't work.

Comment: The `(object)someInt` does something called Boxing. It essentially wraps the int (value type) inside an object reference type.
You're essentially trying to cast a reference type to a value type in your example.

Comment: The word "implicitly" doesn't belong in your answer.  @Matt has an explicit cast, which still fails.