# Why does this typecast cause an error?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

This works as expected:

```
byte b = 7;
var i = (int)b;
```

While this throws an `InvalidCastException`:

```
byte b = 7;
object o = b;
var i = (int)o;
```

Why does the cast fail from an `object` when the underlying type is still `byte`?

Comment: This question explores this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588073/generics-casting-and-value-types-why-is-this-illegal  -- in particular Eric Lippert's answer is good reading.

Comment: @MattGreer That does exactly answer my wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `byte` has an explicit conversion to `int`, but `object` does not.

If you tell the compiler the `object` is *really* a `byte`, then it will once again allow you to explicitly cast to `int`.

```
byte b = 7;
object o = b;
var i = (int)((byte)o);
```

References:

[Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
[byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: ah, just wanted to answer that :P

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the CLRs usage of [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). Whenever you treat a value type as being an object the CLR will automatically box this value type for you inside an Object. The CLR however only support unboxing boxed objects into their original value type as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> **Unboxing**
>
> Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value
>   type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the
>   interface. An unboxing operation consists of:
>
> - **Checking the object instance to make sure that it is a boxed value of the given value type.**
> - Copying the value from the instance into the value-type variable.

`object o = b;` Causes the CLR to created a boxed byte and stores it in o as being an Object. `var i = (int)o;` then attempts to unbox the boxed byte into an int. This causes an exception as the boxed type (byte) and the value type (int) differ.

Answer (score 0):

You must first get the byte from the object before you can *convert* it to an integer.

Something like this:

```
var i = (int)(byte)o;
```