# Why can't I cast int to T, but can cast int to object and then object to T?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

This code does not compile:

```
public T Get<T>()
{
    T result = default(T);
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {    
        int i = 0;
        result = (T)i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

however, this code does compile:

```
public T Get<T>()
{
    T result = default(T);
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {    
        int i = 0;
        result = (T)(object)i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The code also works fine. I don't understand why the compiler can cast an object (actual type could be anything) to T, but cannot cast an int (which inherets from object) to T.

Comment: Can you see the difference where int i is type of int and (T)(Object)i you may want to look at what is boxing and unboxing implicit casting vs explicit casting that what this looks like

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics: casting and value types, why is this illegal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588073/generics-casting-and-value-types-why-is-this-illegal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619952/112407) says, the compiler knows that `T` is convertible to object but that's only half of it. The compiler also knows that any object of type `T` derives from `object`, so it needs to allow downcast from `object` to `T`. Collections pre v2.0 needed this. Not to `T` of course but to be able to downcast from object to any type. It would have been impossible to get anything out of a collection as anything else than an object.

The same is not true when talking about `T` and `int`. Your code is of course safe from those problems at runtime due to the if statement, but the compiler can't see that. In general (not in this case though) proving that you will never get to the body of an if in the case of some external condition being true is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and since we wish the compiler to complete at some point, it's not going to try and basically solve a [millennium prize problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)

There are many scenarios where substituting a specific type for `T` would not be allowed in non-generic code.

If you can't write the code as non-generic for any substitution of `T` with a specific type, it's not valid, not just in this case but generally. If you know that for all your use cases of the method it would actually be valid, you can use [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) to your generic method.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler doesn't know that `T` is `int`. (even though you just proved that it is `int` in your `if`)

By contrast, the compiler does know that `T` is always convertible to `object`.

For example, if `T` is `string`, it's still convertible to `object`, but it's not convertible to `int`.

Comment: So how does it know object is convertible to int?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels: It isn't, not necessarily.  But the compiler knows *how* to do it: perform an unboxing conversion on the `object`, and if the result is an `int`, return that, or else throw an exception.  For comparison, `int x = 1; long y = (long) ((object) x);` will throw for the same reason.  `long y = (long) x;` only works because (and this is the key point) *casting a value type means a __conversion__ takes place*, while casting a reference type does not perform any conversion (at worst, it only performs an unboxing operation).

Comment: I don't see why it can't say:"hmm, I don't know enough about `T` to do any specific type conversion. I do know it's an `object` though, so I'll do conversion as if its an `object`."

Comment: @matthijs The compiler need to be able to determine whether (T)x means convert x to T (E.g if x is int and T is long) unbox Eg. if x is object and T is int, cast E.g. if compile time type of x is object and T is string or call a custom conversion operator (which equals calling a method). Since all for are possible in a generic method, the compiler can't choose one over the other three

Comment: @RuneFS, so if `x` is `int`, could `(long)x` have a different result as `(long)(object)x`?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels: `(long)(object)x` will throw.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: @SLaks, aah and you don't want `(T)x` to throw when `T` is `long`. Cause that should behave like `(long)x`.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels It's possible to have the compiler do a lot. In this case. If you know more than the compiler you can tell the compiler so (cast to object first) and the compiler won't complain that what you are doing might cause a runtime exception. On the other hand if it simply accepted it, you might have less information. You might not realize when you wrote the code that it might not work at runtime