# Unbox a number to double

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

Does some way to cast an unknown number to double exists? For example

```
    public static double Foo(object obj)
    {
        if (!obj.GetType().IsValueType)
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument should be a number", "obj");
        return (double) obj;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double dbl = 10;
        decimal dec = 10;
        int i = 10;
        short s = 10;
        Foo(dbl);
        Foo(dec);
        Foo(i);
        Foo(s);
    }
```

but this code throws an Exception when trying to unbox to improper type.

Comment: Why do you expect that all value types could be casted to `double`? Note that also enums or structs are value types.

Comment: Why don't you use [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToDouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because .Net hasn't easy way to determine if some class is numeric. Anyway, it just was an example, a not-working example.

Comment: @EKrueger, i forgot that Convert works with objects. And not I will use it. Tnx.

Comment: @AshtonWoods it will throw an exception for any type except double. For example, passing integer 10 into method will throw an exception too.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky Ah you're right. The order made me think that the decimal was exceptional. Any ideas why it throws the exception?

Comment: I think I found the answer for the casting exception: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619952/2538037

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx). This does the conversion for you, and works with numeric types, `string`s, and anything else that implements [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) (and has a value that can be converted to a `double`).

```
public static double Foo(object obj)
{
    // you could include a check (IsValueType, or whatever) like you have now,
    // but it's not generally necessary, and rejects things like valid strings
    return Convert.ToDouble(obj);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Tnx. I forgot that Convert works with objects, not with strings only.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDouble` Method converts a specified value to a double-precision floating-point number.

```
public static double Foo(object obj)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fast way to use the `Double.TryParse()`:

```
public static double Foo(object obj)
{
   double result;
   if (double.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out result))
      return result;
   else throw new ArgumentException("Argument should be a number", "obj");
}
```