# How to Cast System.ValueType to Generic Type (T) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, typeconverter, generic-type-argument

I've a C# Code Snippts, which has error as :

> Can not convert System.ValueType to T

Please guide me to solve this

here is a code

```
public static T Add<T>(this Enum type, T value)
{
    try
    {
        return (T) (ValueType) (Convert.ToInt32(type) | (int) (object) value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not append value from enumerated type '{0}'.", (object) typeof (T).Name), ex);
    }
}
```

now how could i run this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generics: casting and value types, why is this illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588073/generics-casting-and-value-types-why-is-this-illegal)

Comment: @Jazb unfortunately no. thic code was run truly in 32 bit version. when we de-compile it and recompile in 64 bit, this errors occurred

Comment: would have been useful to share that to start with...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8)

For example,

```
var result = (ValueType) (Convert.ToInt32(type) | (int) (object) value);
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result,typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no idea that `T` can be upcasted from `ValueType` as it doesn't know that `T` is a value type. You'd need to add the `struct` constraint for that.

```
public static T Add<T>(this Enum type, T value) where T : struct
```

Now that intermediate cast to `ValueType` is equivalent to a cast to `object` and it compiles.

**However**, this cast will fail with an `InvalidCastException` if `T` is anything else than `int` or `int?` (and it can't even be `int?` with a `struct` constraint). That's because doing `(T)(object)` on an `int` first boxes the integer and then tries to unbox it. And a boxed `int` can only be unboxed to an `int` or `int?` (it's true for any value type, you can only unbox a value type `T` to a variable of type `T` or `T?`). So this code being generic is close to useless, as it works with only one type.